# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 when using iAds plugins for Unity in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, iad

I have added the `iAds` plugin from `Prime31` to my Unity project. When I build the project and open it in xCode, everything seems fine.

When I try to build the project using `XCode`, I get the following errors:

Undefined symbols for architecture `armv7`:

> "_*iAdInterstitialIsLoaded", referenced from:
>         RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o   "*_iAdFireHideShowEvents", referenced from:
>         RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o   "_*iAdShowInterstitial", referenced from:
>         RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o   "*_iAdCreateAdBanner", referenced from:
>         RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o   "_*iAdInitializeInterstitial", referenced from:
>         RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o   "*_iAdDestroyAdBanner", referenced from:
>         RegisterMonoModules() in RegisterMonoModules.o

any ideas?

It seems that the error is coming from the `AdBinding.cs` class when doing:

```
[DllImport("__Internal")]
private static extern void _iAdCreateAdBanner( bool bannerOnBottom );
```

along with the other errors...

Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.

Apparently there was a file in Unity that was interfering with the plugin that I imported. 
The game was purchased off of someone else and they had used iAds a different way.

I had to delete their iAds content and then import the plugin I was using. This got rid of the errors in xcode!

Happy coding.